# How can I update NVIDIA driver especially for OpenCL on Google Colab?

Tags: linux, nvidia, google-colaboratory

You can use GPU such as T4, P100 (as well as K80) on Google Colaboratory.
However, the default OpenCL driver does not support half precision features.
I want to use them.

Does the latest driver enable them?
And how can I update NVIDIA driver on Google Colaboratory?

The below is what I tried.

I downloaded the latest driver (XXX.run) from NVIDIA site and

```
!apt remove nvidia-*
# reboot by runtime menu
sh XXX.run
```

But I got

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-uvm' appears to already be loaded in  
        your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X  
        server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this   
        may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for     
        module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be    
        using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no     
        GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports    
        module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error   
        may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage   
        count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
```

I also failed `rmmod nvidia-uvm`.

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.14.137+/modules.builtin.bin'
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'nvidia_uvm': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module nvidia-uvm: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same error. I tried updating Cuda toolkit instead of the drivers but this is not enough for latest Pytorch to run